# SSIS issue in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: ssis

Trying to create a new SSIS Package in Visual Studio 2005, and I keep getting this error message:

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: I think there should be a more detailed error log. Can you post that?

Comment: No detail error log. That's it. Tried a Integration Service project, and that's error message I receive. Are you familiar with this error message?

Comment: Yes, this generally refers to a non existing object(a non nullable object was being referred as null). Are the objects(tables etc.) you are referring is really there?

Comment: No tables have been added to new package yet.  This message comes before project information is displayed in Solution Explorer once it's created.

Comment: Check this out: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/424960be-5c84-48d9-81a9-d4c30eebb847/microsoft-visual-studio-is-unable-to-load-this-document-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of?forum=sqlintegrationservices